# C# code to list all the members of ACL

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am having below VB script code, I want it to be in C# DOT NET.The aim of code is to List the all the members of the specific ACL from LDAP.  Can any one help me.

```
    VB Script:
    Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
    Const adVariant = 12
    iCount = 0

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
    objCommand.CommandText = "Select member from 'LDAP://DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zz,DC=com' where objectClass='group' and name = '" & txtACLName.Text & "'"

    objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
    objCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
    objCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False
    Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
    objRecordSet.MoveFirst

    strMembers = ""
    Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
        For i = 0 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
            arrField = objRecordSet.Fields(i)
            If IsArray(arrField) Then
                For Each strItem In arrField
                    sUser = GetUserId(strItem)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your answer at following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Comment: Hi I tried with the Code given in the link, But for few ACL I am getting proper result, for few I am getting 0 members or very less members. Can anyone let me know the reason.

Comment: How many entries you have for that acl ? There is limitation to that as in some case you get 1000 Or 1500.

Comment: Few ACLs are having more than 5000 members few are less than 200, But I can retrieve them using the VB script , given here http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041800-1.shtml.   But I am not getting the exact code conversion to C#.    Using System.Activedirectory I am getting results only for few ACLs for others it display 0 ( ZERO) result.